# How to define more than one jsp file in web.xml?

Tags: java, jsp

[enter image description here][1] since I'm a newbie to jsp, I'm having lots of doubt buzzing around me.
I need to know how to define more than one jsp file in web.xml.
thanks in advance :).

Comment: You don't "define" jsp files in web.xml. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You need to show your `web.xml`, at least the relevant part.

Comment: @ernest_k I mean how to mention more than one jsp file name in web.xml, I'm expecting that my code should navigate to another jsp page when I'm clicking "click here " button in the current jsp page. I think this might help you to understand.

Comment: use the forms to submit the data when using button to navigate to another page @vigneshwaransundarrajan

Answer (score 0):

We do not declare any JSP files in web.xml, we only mention the initial page to load. by default it could be index.jsp or default.jsp. once the default page is loaded the navigation to another jsp will be handled either bu servlet redeirect method or using href with page name to redirect.

Contact us